# Parsing a local JSON file in Swift to display in table (Type ANY does not conform to protocol sequence)

Tags: json, swift

I know an array of similar questions have been asked and I have looked at, but they don't seem to directly answer what I'm trying to achieve. I have a local JSON file in my directory with a structure similar to this: (it's more like an array than json)

```
"["countrycode1", "country1", "countrycode2", "country2"]" // and so forth
```

I am trying to achieve some sort of collection where the structure can be either be a multi array with the country and codes paired up, or a key value pair collection with the country code as the key and country as the value. The end goal is populating a table with these values with each countrycode and country occupying one row of the table.

Now, I have loaded the json file into my directory and run the following code:

```
func parseJSONData(filename: String){

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "json") {
        do {
              let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
              let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)

            for elements in jsonResult{
                print(elements)
            }

          } catch {
            print(error)
          }
    }
}
```

When trying to loop through the array, I get the error `Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence`. How can I loop through the `jsonResult` to restructure the collection properly or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying? Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `jsonObject(with:` is `Any`, you have to conditionally downcast the type

```
func parseJSONData(filename: String) {

    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json") {
        do {
           let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
           let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
           if let jsonArray = jsonResult as? [String] { // object is an array of strings
              for element in jsonArray {
                 print(element)
              }
           } else if let jsonDictionary = jsonResult as? [String:String] { // object is a dictionary with String keys and values
              for (key, value) in jsonDictionary {
                 print(key, value)
              }
          }   
      } catch {
         print(error)
      }
   }
}
```

Notes:

- There are APIs in `Bundle` to get URLs
- In Swift don't use any `.mutable...` option in `jsonObject(with`

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps you:

```
let array = jsonResult as? [Any] ?? []

for elements in array {
    print(elements)
}
```